# Стилизация Select`а

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте! Как сделать такой select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```css
.container-select{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 34px;    
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container-select:after {
    content:"\2714";    
    color: #000;
    padding: 0 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;      
    line-height: 34px;
    pointer-events: none;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container-select > select{       
    outline: none;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 14px;      
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;    
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-select">
    <select name="select">
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
        <option>option 4</option>
        <option>option 5</option>
        <option>option 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```